# something confusing about when should a defaulted move constructor be deleted

Tags: c++, constructor, default, move

```
class N {
public:
    N() = default;
    N(const N& n) { std::cout << "N copy\n"; };
private:
    char c;
};

class H {
public:
    H() = default;
    H(H&) { std::cout << "H copy\n"; }
    H(H&&) = default;
private:
    N n;
};

int main() {
    N n1, n2 = std::move(n1);
    H h1, h2 = std::move(h1);
}
```

In VS2016, I define class N to see what would happen if the move constructor is neither defined nor synthesized by the compiler; and define class H to see what would happen if the defaulted move constructor is deleted.

In the main function, executing the first statement prints "N copy", which means copy constructor is called because there's no move constructor in N.

**What I can't understand is, executing the second statement "h2 = std::move(h1)" also prints "N copy".**

As I've read in C++ Primer(it's based on C++11), the defaulted move constructor of a class will be defined as deleted if the class has a member that defines its own copy constructor but doesn't define move constructor. Since the member n meets that condition, the move constructor of H should be deleted, "h2 = std::move(h1)" should call the copy constructor and thus print "H copy".

However, only "N copy" is printed, which means the copy constructor of H is not called, but the copy constructor of N is called. Why?

---

Here's what I guess:

The compiler still synthesized a move constructor for H, and it works like this:

```
H(H&& h) :n(std::move(h.n)) {}
```

Here the move constructor tries to move member n, and just like what happened in "N n1, n2 = std::move(n1);", the copy constructor of N is called, thus "N copy" is printed.

---

This explanation does make sense, **but according to C++ Primer, the default move constructor of H should have been defined as delete.** It's the copy constructor of H that should be called.

So I'm confused: is the book wrong? Or is this some new property introduced by new standard? Or is this caused by the compiler?

Comment: This is [core issue 1402](https://wg21.link/CWG1402).

Comment: Thanks, now I understand that this is some kind of modification brought by C++14.

Answer (score 1):

What surprises you? You have a defaulted move constructor for H, and it is going to call move or copy constructors for all it's members. There is only one member, type of `N`, which doesn't have move constructor - so the copy constructor of `N` is called. This is why you see your printout.

Comment: Because according to C++ Primer, the default move constructor of H should have been defined as delete, but the result indicates it's not deleted, so I'm surprised.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand that this is some kind of modification brought by C++14